Python way to setup the Menu Switch default value when exposed to the modifiers input
I need to setup the default value in the geometry modifiers which is from a Menu Switch node. I tried two ways, neither worked.

bpy.context.object.modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Socket_2"] = 'A' will give an warning as the picture shows.
node_tree.interface.items_tree[2].default_value = 'A' no warning but do nothing.
I have a minimum working code (line 79 and 80) to test. Just copy to text editor and hit run.
import bpy

def update_geoNode_tree(node_tree):
    
    group_output = node_tree.nodes["Group Output"]
    group_input = node_tree.nodes["Group Input"]
   
    #Socket Menu
    menu_socket = node_tree.interface.new_socket(name = "Menu", in_out='INPUT', socket_type = 'NodeSocketMenu')
    menu_socket.attribute_domain = 'POINT'
    
    #node Menu Switch
    menu_switch = node_tree.nodes.new("GeometryNodeMenuSwitch")
    menu_switch.name = "Menu Switch"
    
    #node Cylinder
    cylinder = node_tree.nodes.new("GeometryNodeMeshCylinder")
    cylinder.name = "Cylinder"
    cylinder.fill_type = 'NGON'
    #Vertices
    cylinder.inputs[0].default_value = 32
    #Side Segments
    cylinder.inputs[1].default_value = 1
    #Fill Segments
    cylinder.inputs[2].default_value = 1
    #Radius
    cylinder.inputs[3].default_value = 1.0
    #Depth
    cylinder.inputs[4].default_value = 1.0
    
    #node Cube
    cube = node_tree.nodes.new("GeometryNodeMeshCube")
    cube.name = "Cube"
    #Size
    cube.inputs[0].default_value = (1.0, 1.0, 3.0)

    #Set locations
    group_input.location = (-340.9637451171875, 39.62562561035156)
    group_output.location = (326.51617431640625, 65.04036712646484)
    menu_switch.location = (55.20476531982422, 51.1171760559082)
    cylinder.location = (-343.1625671386719, -62.844444274902344)
    cube.location = (-169.79373168945312, -105.80216217041016)
    
    #Set dimensions
    group_input.width, group_input.height = 140.0, 100.0
    group_output.width, group_output.height = 140.0, 100.0
    menu_switch.width, menu_switch.height = 140.0, 100.0
    cylinder.width, cylinder.height = 140.0, 100.0
    cube.width, cube.height = 140.0, 100.0
    
    #initialize node_tree links
    #menu_switch.Output -> group_output.Geometry
    node_tree.links.new(menu_switch.outputs[0], group_output.inputs[0])
    #cylinder.Mesh -> menu_switch.A
    node_tree.links.new(cylinder.outputs[0], menu_switch.inputs[1])
    #cube.Mesh -> menu_switch.B
    node_tree.links.new(cube.outputs[0], menu_switch.inputs[2])
    #group_input.Menu -> menu_switch.Menu
    node_tree.links.new(group_input.outputs[1], menu_switch.inputs[0])
    
    return node_tree

def create_centerpiece():
    
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add()
    bpy.context.active_object.name = 'testGeoTree'

    bpy.ops.node.new_geometry_nodes_modifier()
    node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups["Geometry Nodes"]
    node_tree.name = "testGeoTree"

    update_geoNode_tree(node_tree)

    # make the Geo Nodes modifier the active mode at the end
    bpy.context.active_object.modifiers["GeometryNodes"].is_active = True
    
    ##############################################
    #### for question to test
    #bpy.context.object.modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Socket_2"] = 'A'
    #node_tree.interface.items_tree[2].default_value = 'A'
    ##############################################


def main():
    """
    Python code to generate geo nodes node tree
    """
   
    create_centerpiece()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()



I figure it out. The options are indexed, so giving the index value to change the value instead of the string.
bpy.context.object.modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Socket_2"] = 0
